# Uploading a form's file without submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file

Currently I have the following code:

```
  <div id="insertreading">Insert Reading</div>
        <form id="confirmreadingform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" style="display: none;">
          <input id="uploadreading" name="fileToUpload2" type="file" value="Upload Resources"/>
       </form>
    </div>
    <div id="submitchanges">Submit Changes</div>
```

Basically I want it so that when submitchanges is clicked, it will take the file the user has entered in the form and a php script will process/get the file(using $_FILES). I know I could just use an action="upload.php" in the form but is it possible without it. Would I need to use Ajax?

Is the following correct:

```
var formData = new FormData($("#confirmreadingform"));
    formData.append('reading', $('#uploadreading'));
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'upload.php',
        data: formData,
         success: function (data) {
           alert(data)
         },
    });
```

Comment: Yes - the other way is to use AJAX. And have you tries you AJAX script - it looks good? If there would be issues - update the question.

Comment: It throws : Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: add this to your ajax options:
contentType: false, processData: false,

Comment: Thank you, that one works. But now when the php script is getting called I'm getting Undefined index: reading in C:\mypath\upload.php when I try to access it via $_FILES['reading']['name']